# send serial port data to front-end with express & node

Tags: express, serial-port

I want to send serial port data to a browser UI with express. So far my code looks like this:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem1421");

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var datenFromA;

serialport.on('open', function(){
 console.log('Serial Port Opend');
 serialport.on('data', function(data){
   datenFromA = data[0];
   console.log(datenFromA);
 });
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Instead of the `'Hello World'` I want to send the value of variable `datenFromA` to the browser. Any ideas how to pass the value to the app.get function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to wait until you receive an event. Quick dirty example given below:

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem1421");

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Only need to do this once.
serialport.on('open', () => console.log('Serial Port Opend'));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    serialport.on('data', (data, err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(data[0]);
    });
  })

  const data = await promise;

  res.json(data);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But the value doesn't update automatically, I have to refresh the browser to get the newer value. Do you have an idea how to constantly update the value with the new data?

Comment: I would recommend using/looking into [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). So when you receive data on the serial port, you would fire off a server event which your client would receive.